# PHP Page execution

Tags: php, apache, ibm-cloud, execution-time

I have created a PHP application where an image file is downloaded from a link and is stored in the local folder. From there it is uploaded back again to FTP folder.

The image size is 27 MB. Well the file is downloading and uploading back again with no problem as the script is initiated but my page stops loading after some time. Because of that whatever output it has to display it is not displaying. Now it is displaying as a blank page.

- I tired setting `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` in my php page.
- I have increased my timeout value in httpd-default.conf.
- I also have changed the following values in php.ini

1) max_execution_time = 30000 // though i have set '0' in my php file.

2) max_input_time = 60

3) memory_limit = 512M

4) Have set file_uploads = On

5) upload_max_filesize = 2000M

6) max_file_uploads = 200

6) allow_url_include = On

Well the important point here is I'm running this application in **Bluemix**. Is there anything else that I should look into ?.

Edited:

I don't have any problem with small files sizes. It only happens with big images files.

I have pasted my log below:

2016-03-26T15:33:59.715+0530 [RTR/0] OUT  dmrst.au-syd.mybluemix.net - [26/03/2016:10:03:59 +0000] 
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 867 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36" 168.1.55.103:60047 x_forwarded_for:"61.16.162.202" x_forwarded_proto:"http" vcap_request_id:f1e5381f-5e43-426c-57b8-e948889726ad response_time:0.003732228 app_id:be513862-de63-4b71-bef3-1c78d56d8414 x_global_transaction_id:"13332023"

2016-03-26T15:33:59.740+0530 [App/0] OUT 10:03:59 httpd | 168.1.44.156 - - [26/Mar/2016:10:03:59 +0000]
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 867 vcap_request_id=f1e5381f-5e43-426c-57b8-e948889726ad peer_addr=168.1.44.156

Comment: Blank page could mean anything. Have you checked the headers your browser is receiving, and the page source? Have you looked at the apache access and error logs? Is it a timeout or something else?

Comment: Are there .htaccess files in your Bluemix folder structure that mention timeouts and such? Or Bluemix configuration files?

Comment: Just a thought: you might want to consider making this an asynchronous process. You use the webapplication to give the *order* to copy the file, but the actual copying of the file is done by a script running in the background, so that you don't have to worry about timeouts. Background script and webapplication can communicate via database or file. The webpage regularly refreshes itself to show the status of the upload. Idea?

Comment: I didn't come across .htaccess  file in the structure but i have increased the timeout in httpd-default.conf. I will look into asynchronous process that you suggested. Do you know about browser timeout ? I haven't tried that yet. Please tell  me if you know anything about it.

Comment: In firefox you can set of disable timeout values in the about:config page - don't know about other browsers. In theory a browser could wait for a request to complete indefinitely.